# how to parse a date string like "5th Apr 1920" in java8

Tags: java, date, java-8

```
String date = "5th Apr 1920";   
LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

this prases DateTimeParseException.

If pattern is "d'th' MMM yyyy", it works. But it is unsuitable when string is "1st Apr 1920".

Answer (score 1):

Just specify more options:

```
LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter
  .ofPattern("d['th']['st']['nd']['rd'] MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH))
```